# getting button value in onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, bind

I am trying get the button value in a onChange event.Later I will have to bind the value to `state`. But I am getting an empty value.

```
<button onChange={this.handleCategoryName}  onClick={this.goToNextPage}>
    Restaurant
</button>
```

This is the event where I am trying to get the value "Restaurant"

```
handleCategoryName(event) {  this.setState({ categoryName:event.target.innerHTML });   }
```

and it's `state` where I will bind the button value.

```
this.state = {
    apiUrl: config.publicRuntimeConfig.publicRuntimeConfigValue.apiUrl,
    value: 850,
    categoryName: " ",
};
this.handleCategoryName = this.handleCategoryName.bind(this);
```

But I am getting an empty value in my database.

```
axios.post( this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/LeadSurvey/save', {
            'categoryName':this.state.categoryName,
           }
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I don't think buttons have onChange property, try getting the value from the `goToNextPage` function

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the onChange event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that buttons can't have a `onChange` property. Why? Because buttons don't have a field to change with. All the elements in HTML who can be used with a `onChange` property have a field. When they change, it can trigger something. Buttons just have plain text that explains it or nothing at all if you don't need text on the buttons and the text can't change without doing some fancy functions. Even though buttons can click, you can't directly use the `onChange` property with them. The `onChange` property is the `onClick` property with buttons. So I suggest that the `onChange` event property should be removed and replaced with something else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use an `<input>` field to get the `categoryName`, as it looks like you want to get input and also have a button with an `onClick` event.  I would recommend checking out [W3Schools' page on the `<input>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).  You will be able to use the `<input>` tag with the `onChange` attribute.

Comment: StackOverflow is not about guessing, it's about knowing.